# iOS AutoFill feature: is there a way to intercept an AutoFill event?

Tags: ios, swift, autofill

Whenever a password is filled in the app's login form, I think it would be nice to hide the keyboard and automatically proceed with the login, pretty much like it happens on most web sites with Safari.

Is there a way for an app to detect an AutoFill event?